# Changing default program to open in using Sublime Text 3

Tags: sublimetext3

I'm using Sublime Text 3 and developing Javascript. I pressed f12 to open the file, where it asked me to choose a default program - to which I accidentally selected Visual Studio.

Now, whenever I press f12 it opens in Visual Studio - how do I change what program it opens in?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.

For people having the same problem, on the desktop change the default program (right click, open with) and then the f12 in Sublime will work brilliantly.

Thanks!